# Add custom fields in custom taxonomy meta box in wordpress-3.5.2

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

Unable to add custom fields in custom taxonomy meta box in wordpress-3.5.2.

I have checked solution in various blogs but Unable to solved this problem. I am using wordpress-3.5.2

What I am trying is :-

```
// A callback function to add a custom field to our "adtag" taxonomy
add_action( 'adtag_edit_form_fields', 'adtag_callback_function', 10, 2);

// A callback function to save our extra taxonomy field(s) 
add_action( 'edited_adtag', 'save_taxonomy_custom_fields', 10, 2 );
```

I have tried solution from below link:-

http://www.codehooligans.com/2010/07/07/custom-meta-for-new-taxonomies-in-wordpress-3-0/
http://sabramedia.com/blog/how-to-add-custom-fields-to-custom-taxonomies

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-additional-custom-meta-fields-to-custom-taxonomies/

http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/add-term-or-taxonomy-meta-data

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the **Tax-meta-class** developed to add extra fields to taxonomies: [WordPress Taxonomies Extra Fields the easy way](https://en.bainternet.info/wordpress-taxonomies-extra-fields-the-easy-way/#toc-su)

**1) Include the main class file**

```
require_once("Tax-meta-class/Tax-meta-class.php");
```

**2) Configure taxonomy custom fields**

```
$config = array(
    'id' => 'demo_meta_box',
    'title' => 'Demo Meta Box',
    'pages' => array('category'),
    'context' => 'normal',
    'fields' => array(),
    'local_images' => false,
    'use_with_theme' => false
);
```

**3) Initiate your taxonomy custom fields**

```
$my_meta = new Tax_Meta_Class($config);
```

**4) Add fields**

```
//text field
$my_meta->addText('text_field_id',array('name'=> 'My Text '));
//textarea field
$my_meta->addTextarea('textarea_field_id',array('name'=> 'My Textarea '));
```

**5) Finish Taxonomy Extra fields Deceleration [important!]**

```
$my_meta->Finish();
```

**6) Getting Saved data**

```
$saved_data = get_tax_meta($term_id,'text_field_id');
echo $saved_data;
```

Comment: Link is broken and maybe even infected. Avaast Security blocks the page.

Comment: I The link works for me and with various tools it appears to be safe. I think it's a problem with your Avast (it's not the first time that an antivirus has blocked a web page by mistakenly deeming it dangerous)

Comment: You are right. The link works. I thought I'd tried it to open with browserstack and that the page did not show up. Not the case, it looks all good. Sorry for the false alarm.

Answer (score 2):

To add a custom field to your custom taxonomy, add the following code to your theme's **functions.php**:

```
// A callback function to add a custom field to our "presenters" taxonomy  
function presenters_taxonomy_custom_fields($tag) {  
   // Check for existing taxonomy meta for the term you're editing  
    $t_id = $tag->term_id; // Get the ID of the term you're editing  
    $term_meta = get_option( "taxonomy_term_$t_id" ); // Do the check  
?>  

<tr class="form-field">  
    <th scope="row" valign="top">  
        <label for="presenter_id"><?php _e('WordPress User ID'); ?></label>  
    </th>  
    <td>  
        <input type="text" name="term_meta[presenter_id]" id="term_meta[presenter_id]" size="25" style="width:60%;" value="<?php echo $term_meta['presenter_id'] ? $term_meta['presenter_id'] : ''; ?>"><br />  
        <span class="description"><?php _e('The Presenter\'s WordPress User ID'); ?></span>  
    </td>  
</tr>  

<?php  
}
```

Next, we'll create a callback function that we'll use to save our custom fields. Add the following code to your theme's **functions.php**:

```
// A callback function to save our extra taxonomy field(s)  
function save_taxonomy_custom_fields( $term_id ) {  
    if ( isset( $_POST['term_meta'] ) ) {  
        $t_id = $term_id;  
        $term_meta = get_option( "taxonomy_term_$t_id" );  
        $cat_keys = array_keys( $_POST['term_meta'] );  
            foreach ( $cat_keys as $key ){  
            if ( isset( $_POST['term_meta'][$key] ) ){  
                $term_meta[$key] = $_POST['term_meta'][$key];  
            }  
        }  
        //save the option array  
        update_option( "taxonomy_term_$t_id", $term_meta );  
    }  
}
```

The code above will work "as is" for one or more custom taxonomies, no changes needed.

now let's associate these callback functions to the "edit" screen for our custom taxonomies. To do that, we'll use two of the WordPress action hooks that are available for each custom taxonomy that we create. Add the following code to your theme's **functions.php**:

```
// Add the fields to the "presenters" taxonomy, using our callback function  
add_action( 'presenters_edit_form_fields', 'presenters_taxonomy_custom_fields', 10, 2 );  

// Save the changes made on the "presenters" taxonomy, using our callback function  
add_action( 'edited_presenters', 'save_taxonomy_custom_fields', 10, 2 );
```

To access a custom field added to your custom taxonomy
add the following code inside your custom taxonomy template (example, taxonomy-presenters.php), within the PHP block at the top:

```
// Get the custom fields based on the $presenter term ID  
$presenter_custom_fields = get_option( "taxonomy_term_$presenter->term_id" );  

// Return the value for the "presenter_id" custom field  
$presenter_data = get_userdata( $presenter_custom_fields[presenter_id] ); // Get their data
```

For this example to work, be sure that you have saved a value in the custom field for the term you are working with.

```
<?php  
    echo '<pre>';  
    print_r( $presenter_custom_fields );  
    echo '</pre>';  
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to follow the directions on http://sabramedia.com/blog/how-to-add-custom-fields-to-custom-taxonomies to create custom fields within a custom taxonomy.

It looks like you are not including the steps after adding the action. Make sure you are working in the functions.php file and that you include the html markup for how the custom field should appear. That is, this section from the SabraMedia instructions:

```
// A callback function to add a custom field to our "presenters" taxonomy  
function presenters_taxonomy_custom_fields($tag) {  
   // Check for existing taxonomy meta for the term you're editing  
    $t_id = $tag->term_id; // Get the ID of the term you're editing  
    $term_meta = get_option( "taxonomy_term_$t_id" ); // Do the check  
?>  

<tr class="form-field">  
    <th scope="row" valign="top">  
        <label for="presenter_id"><?php _e('WordPress User ID'); ?></label>  
    </th>  
    <td>  
        <input type="text" name="term_meta[presenter_id]" id="term_meta[presenter_id]" size="25" style="width:60%;" value="<?php echo $term_meta['presenter_id'] ? $term_meta['presenter_id'] : ''; ?>"><br />  
        <span class="description"><?php _e('The Presenter\'s WordPress User ID'); ?></span>  
    </td>  
</tr>  

<?php  
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot @Summer at least you give me answer. I have found something better solution after lots of R&D . what I did here overwrite custom taxonomy function. and write our own similar function as core post_tag taxonomy provided to us. I have add my fields in that function . It will give me all custom field including custom taxonomy fields...

Comment: In your solution it will create taxonomy page only for taxonomy page. when taxonomy use in edit or add page it only give single taxonomy field. So my requirement was little bit different here. I need that custom fields in add or edit page as well.

Answer (score 1):

The creation / edition of an existing taxonomy, whether customized or not, has two panels.

The first panel to create a new term for the taxonomy normally consisting of meta fields

- Name
- Slug

And the second panel to edit an existing term

To add custom fields to the taxonomy term **creation panel**, first panel, use:

```
<?php
// Key of your custom taxonomy goes here.
// Taxonomy key, must not exceed 32 characters.
$prefix_taxonomy = 'category';
 
/**
 * This will add the custom meta field to the add new term page.
 *
 * @return void
 */
function wporg_prefix_add_meta_fields(){
    ?>
 
    <div class="form-field term-meta-wrap">
        <label for="term_meta[custom_term_meta]">
            <?php esc_html_e( 'Example meta field', 'textdomain' ); ?>
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="term_meta[custom_term_meta]" id="term_meta[custom_term_meta]" value="" />
        <p class="description">
            <?php esc_html_e( 'Enter a value for this field.', 'textdomain' ); ?>
        </p>
    </div>
     
    <?php
}
add_action( sprintf( '%s_add_form_fields', $prefix_taxonomy ), 'wporg_prefix_add_meta_fields' );
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/taxonomy_edit_form_fields/

To add custom fields to the **edit panel**, second panel, use:

```
<?php
// A callback function to add a custom field to our "presenters" taxonomy  
function presenters_taxonomy_custom_fields($tag) {  
   // Check for existing taxonomy meta for the term you're editing  
    $t_id = $tag->term_id; // Get the ID of the term you're editing  
    $term_meta = get_option( "taxonomy_term_$t_id" ); // Do the check  
?>  

<tr class="form-field">  
    <th scope="row" valign="top">  
        <label for="presenter_id"><?php _e('WordPress User ID'); ?></label>  
    </th>  
    <td>  
        <input type="text" name="term_meta[presenter_id]" id="term_meta[presenter_id]" size="25" style="width:60%;" value="<?php echo $term_meta['presenter_id'] ? $term_meta['presenter_id'] : ''; ?>"><br />  
        <span class="description"><?php _e('The Presenter\'s WordPress User ID'); ?></span>  
    </td>  
</tr>  

<?php  
}  
// Add the fields to the "presenters" taxonomy, using our callback function  
add_action( 'presenters_edit_form_fields', 'presenters_taxonomy_custom_fields', 10, 2 );
```

https://sabramedia.com/blog/how-to-add-custom-fields-to-custom-taxonomies