# Extra options for Custom taxonomies Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I have to add simple options to my custom taxonomy (genre) for each custom post included in that specific taxonomy.

- **Taxonomy name:** Genre
- **Taxonomies:** Blues, Jazz, Rock
- **Custom post name:** Bands
- **Bands:** Band One, Band Two Band Three, Band Four

So basically going to the **Jazz** taxonomy options, should give me options for the Jazz **bands**:

- Band Two {text_field}
- Band Four {text_field}

I'm not achieving this with Advanced Custom Fields so I guess I need to write it? Or is there a plugin to save my life? If not where should I start looking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you mean is that you want to *extend* your custom taxonomy to have more fields that the default: `Name`, `Slug` and `Description`, you can:

1. Use a massive plugin like [**Pods**](http://pods.io/), which allows you to do what you want to do and much more stuff. See their [**docs**](http://pods.io/docs/build/how-to-extend-a-taxonomy-with-custom-fields/).
2. Use a simple plugin like [**Tax-Meta-class**](https://github.com/bainternet/Tax-Meta-Class), intended just for that purpose, which does not add many (probably unnecesary) code.
3. Try to do it *manually*, like in [**this example**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20454333/1813625).

Note that I have not used any of these, but I'd strongly suggest you to try the **option 2**.

---

***EDIT***
Actually, if you're already using Advanced Custom Fields plugin, it allows you to do what you're looking for!

You just need to create a new Field Group and set up the custom fields you want as usual. Then, in the box **Location**, you need to set a **Rule** like this:

> *Show this field group if* 
>  **Taxonomy Term** ----- **equals to** -----
>   **Genre**

This way you have all the power of ACF to create select-boxes or whatever you need...

---

***EDIT 2***
If what you want is to have different custom fields in a **Post**, depending on the **Terms** that this post has for a given taxonomy, you have to set up a Rule for your Field Group like this:

> *Show this field group if* 
>  **Post Taxonomy** ----- **equals to** -----
>   **Jazz**

This will display this Field Group in all the *Bands* with a value of *Jazz* in the *Genre* taxonomy...

Comment: Thanks, I'm testing the Tex-Meta-class plugin. I'll probably get it to do what I want.

Comment: Actually, to be sure, I'm not finding a way to do exactly what I need with Tax-Meta-Class. I can add some fields, no problem. But I need the taxonomy-options to output a list of the Bands included in that taxonomy and a input field for each band. Am I missing something basic?

Comment: @LeopoldKristjansson. I can't tell about Tax-Meta-Class because I've never used it, but see my edit and try to do it using Advanced Custom Fields

Comment: thanks again for the edit. I already had many simple extra fields for my taxonomies using ACF. However, the problem is that I can't seem to get this relationship I'm trying to achieve. That is an option for each post in the genre taxonomy. Do you get what I mean? **Band one - some option field | Band two - some option field | Band three - some option field** The option field could for example be a text field.

Comment: @LeopoldKristjansson, see my new edit. If this is not what you mean either, please re-write your question because I don't get it...